# Creating a new complex entry on OData [sapui]

Tags: odata, sapui5, olingo

I have this complex OData model:

```
<EntityType Name="ApprovalsRequest">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="IdUser"/>
<PropertyRef Name="RequestId"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="ApprovalTime" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="IdUser" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="RequestId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Request" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="User" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="RequestDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ApprovalsRequest_Request_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="ApprovalsRequest" ToRole="Request"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="UserDetails" Relationship="rva-persistence.ApprovalsRequest_User_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="ApprovalsRequest" ToRole="User"/>
</EntityType>
```

This model have two relationships with another models.

I'm trying to create a new entry of this model.

I have the following XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:entry xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <a:author>
      <a:name />
   </a:author>
   <a:content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
         <d:IdUser>1</d:IdUser>
         <d:RequestId>1</d:RequestId>
         <d:Request>1</d:Request>
         <d:User>1</d:User>
         <d:ApprovalTime>19/5/2017 9:58:00</d:ApprovalTime>
         <d:Status>1</d:Status>
      </m:properties>
   </a:content>
   <a:link href="http://localhost:8080/rva_backend_ui5/incloud_backend.svc/Users(1)" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/UsersDetails" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" />
   <a:link href="http://localhost:8080/rva_backend_ui5/incloud_backend.svc/Requests(1)" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/RequestDetails" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" />
</a:entry>
```

When I try to send this request I get an erro message:

```
The request body is malformed
```

What's wrong with my XML request?

thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I've changed values of ApprovalTime attribute:

```
<d:ApprovalTime>2015-07-14T05:00:00</d:ApprovalTime>
```

But, I get another errors (I'm usin Apache Olingo for mapping JPA entities as OData objects):

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: la columna «id_user» es de tipo integer pero la expresión es de tipo character varying
  Hint: Necesitará reescribir la expresión o aplicarle una conversió
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.incloud.hcp.entity.ApprovalsRequest@243f0e32)
```

This is log:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: la columna «id_user» es de tipo integer pero la expresión es de tipo character varying
  Hint: Necesitará reescribir la expresión o aplicarle una conversión de tipo.
  Position: 96
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO approvals_request (approval_time, STATUS, request_id, id_user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [2015-07-14 00:00:00.0, 1, 1, null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.incloud.hcp.entity.ApprovalsRequest@243f0e32)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1991)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1726)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4196)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.core.ODataJPATransactionLocalDefault.commit(ODataJPATransactionLocalDefault.java:43)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.core.access.data.JPAProcessorImpl.processCreate(JPAProcessorImpl.java:341)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.core.access.data.JPAProcessorImpl.process(JPAProcessorImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.ODataJPADefaultProcessor.createEntity(ODataJPADefaultProcessor.java:115)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:79)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.ODataRequestHandler.handle(ODataRequestHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.ODataSubLocator.handle(ODataSubLocator.java:164)
    at org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.ODataSubLocator.handlePost(ODataSubLocator.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:261)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:100)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.incloud.hcp.service.factory.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:168)
    at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:94)
    at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:37)
    at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: la columna «id_user» es de tipo integer pero la expresión es de tipo character varying
  Hint: Necesitará reescribir la expresión o aplicarle una conversión de tipo.
  Position: 96
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 90 more
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've solved my problem. My XML request was wrong, This is correted request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:entry xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <a:author>
      <a:name />
   </a:author>
   <a:content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
         <d:IdUser>1</d:IdUser>
         <d:RequestId>1</d:RequestId>
         <d:Request>1</d:Request>
         <d:User>2</d:User>
         <d:ApprovalTime>2015-07-14T05:00:00</d:ApprovalTime>
         <d:Status>1</d:Status>
      </m:properties>
   </a:content>
   <a:link href="http://localhost:8080/rva_backend_ui5/incloud_backend.svc/Requests(1)" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/RequestDetails" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" />
   <a:link href="http://localhost:8080/rva_backend_ui5/incloud_backend.svc/Users(1)" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/UserDetails" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" />
</a:entry>
```

One of link' url was wrong:

Incorrect version:

```
<a:link href="http://localhost:8080/rva_backend_ui5/incloud_backend.svc/Users(1)" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/UsersDetails" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" />
```

Correct version (UserDetails instead of UsersDetails):

```
<a:link href="http://localhost:8080/rva_backend_ui5/incloud_backend.svc/Users(1)" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/UserDetails" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" />
```

Comment: Greetings! I am wondering if you are using v4 odata, because I can't seem to be able to properly configure the navigation properties in the backend..

Comment: I'm woking with OLingo v4. This request is generated for my web client (I use SAPUI). I've created a JSON object and when It is sended to server generates a request on XML format

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain a little bit more about the java part. I have created a test type and entity set with navigation properties, but even with the $expand option, the olingo fails parsing the result.... Is it possible to provide some snippets with the org.apache.olingo.commons.api.data.Entity  class used in the backend? Or you are not using it and returning custom response?

Comment: Later, I will post some relative to OData complex entries but using SAPUI. My client is a web app on SAPUI, not in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that stands out is the datetime format you are using. The right format is described in the [documentation here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/).

> 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm[:ss[.fffffff]]' NOTE: Spaces are not allowed between datetime and quoted portion. datetime is case-insensitive

(the *datetime* portion is left out as stated in the [atom format](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/atom-format/))

Answer (score 0):

It is very tedious and error prone to hand code the request body of an OData XML request. Rather I would suggest you use json. 
Also for understanding the expected formats, try performing a 'READ', and look for the various formats.

Comment: Sorry but I just have captured request sended to server from web app on SAPUI. In SAPUI I use ODataModel and this generate request in XML format